# Listar tabelas que possuem trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Existe alguma forma de saber quais as tabelas que possuem ao menos 1 trigger ?

Por exemplo, tenho um sistema com 10.000 tabelas, e gostaria de saber quais delas tem trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31292834/4551469) em uma pergunta do *SOEN*, acredito que vai te resolver:

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName, tr.name AS TriggerName  
FROM sys.triggers tr
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = tr.parent_id
```

Entendo que serão listadas as tabelas e as triggers relacionadas; na resposta é adicionada a tabela como filtro, removi para que todas sejam listadas;